# Distributions and primitives

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

I was wondering: if distributions are seen as a generalization of functions that "removes obstructions" to the operation of derivation, is there a generalization of functions that would remove any obstruction to the operation of integration, i.e. that would make any "function" have a primitive?

Comment: Kurzweil-Henstock integral.

Comment: @Lolman - I would be more interested in the resulting space of "functions" than in technical ways to compute any integral.

Comment: You have a function and you want to obtain a number from it in some meaningful way. The Kurzweil-Henstock integral gives you the most general framework, that is to say the vastest class of integrable functions. What is it I am missing?

Comment: I'm seeing the problem from a different point of view: if D is an operation that gives f' = D(f), D does not meet any obstruction on the set of distributions. If P is an operation that gives F = P(f), F the primitive of f, what would be a set of "functions" on which P does not meet any obstruction? I'm seeing the fact that P is "obstructed" (not always feasible to find P) as a signal that usual functions are not the right setting for integration. Integration can be seen as measuring f, but it can also be seen as a link between f and F, without measuring anything.

Comment: You do understand that your saying "D does not meet any obstruction on the set of distributions." is exactly as saying that the classic derivative "does not meet any obstruction on the set $C^\infty$."? In the same way one defines the set of functions that admit integral. That is $L^1(\mu)$ when $\mu$ is a probability measure. And in that sense Henstock-Kurzweil integral get the answer for generality.